# Individually moving z labels gives error in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween, ticks

If I add the vertical blue plane to this tikzpicture I lose the ability to individually move the z tick label, i.e. I get the error

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> (\tick
                  == -1)*0.1em
```

so I have to comment the code used to move the z tick labels around, resulting in an overlapping.

The weird thing is that if I comment the code to display the plane:

```
\addplot[fill = blue, opacity = 0.4, samples = 2] fill between [of = top and bottom];
```

then I can move the z tick labels without any problem. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

This is the full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\fonts}[1]{\fontsize{#1pt}{#1pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% tick label font and positioning
\pgfplotsset{
% x labels
every x tick label/.append style = {font = \fonts{11}, 
xshift = {(\tick == -6.28)* 0.04em},    yshift = {(\tick == -6.28)*0.3em},
xshift = {(\tick == -3.14)*-0.38em},    yshift = {(\tick == -3.14)*0.4em},
xshift = {(\tick == 0)*-0.28em},        yshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.25em},
xshift = {(\tick == 3.14)*-0.28em},     yshift = {(\tick == 3.14)*0.25em},
xshift = {(\tick == 6.28)*-0.26em},     yshift = {(\tick == 6.28)*0.34em}},
% y labels
every y tick label/.append style = {font = \fonts{11}, 
xshift = {(\tick == -6.28)*0.35em},     yshift = {(\tick == -6.28)*1em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == -3.14)*0.22em},     yshift = {(\tick == -3.14)*0.76em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.28em},         yshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.45em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == 3.14)*0.28em},      yshift = {(\tick == 3.14)*0.45em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == 6.28)*0.25em},      yshift = {(\tick == 6.28)*0.56em}}}
% z labels
%every z tick label/.style = {font = \fonts{11}, 
%xshift = {(\tick == -1)*0.1em},        yshift = {(\tick == -1)*0.5em}, 
%xshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.1em},     yshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.15em}, 
%xshift = {(\tick == 1)*0.1em},         yshift = {(\tick == 1)*0.1em}}}
% axis
\begin{axis}[
xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$, width = 10cm, view={30}{60}, 
ymin = -2*pi, ymax = 2*pi,
zmin = -1, zmax = 1, 
xtick = {-6.28, -3.14,..., 6.28}, 
ytick = {-6.28, -3.14,..., 6.28}, 
xticklabels = {$-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $0$, $\pi$, $2\pi$}, 
yticklabels = {$-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $0$, $\pi$, $2\pi$}]
% plot (samples = 65)
\addplot3[surf, samples = 5, domain = -2*pi:2*pi, y domain = -pi:2*pi, opacity = 0.5] {sin(deg(x))*cos(deg(y))};
\addplot3[domain = -2*pi:2*pi, fill = blue, opacity = 0.1, name path = top] (x, -pi, 1);
\addplot3[domain = -2*pi:2*pi, fill = blue, opacity = 0.1, name path = bottom] (x, -pi, -1);
\addplot3[fill = blue, opacity = 0.4, samples = 2] fill between [of = top and bottom];
\addplot3[domain = -2*pi:2*pi, line width = 1, samples=60, samples y = 0] ({x}, {-pi}, {-sin(deg(x))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting for an explanation (which I can't give), I can supply a workaround:

```
\addplot3[fill = blue, opacity = 0.4] coordinates {(-6.28,-3.14,-1)(6.28,-3.14,-1)(6.28,-3.14,1)(-6.28,-3.14,1)(-6.28,-3.14,-1)};
```

So certainly less convenient than using `fill between`, but it does work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\fonts}[1]{\fontsize{#1pt}{#1pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
% \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% tick label font and positioning
\pgfplotsset{
% x labels
every x tick label/.append style = {font = \fonts{11}, 
xshift = {(\tick == -6.28)* 0.04em},    yshift = {(\tick == -6.28)*0.3em},
xshift = {(\tick == -3.14)*-0.38em},    yshift = {(\tick == -3.14)*0.4em},
xshift = {(\tick == 0)*-0.28em},        yshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.25em},
xshift = {(\tick == 3.14)*-0.28em},     yshift = {(\tick == 3.14)*0.25em},
xshift = {(\tick == 6.28)*-0.26em},     yshift = {(\tick == 6.28)*0.34em}},
% y labels
every y tick label/.append style = {font = \fonts{11}, 
xshift = {(\tick == -6.28)*0.35em},     yshift = {(\tick == -6.28)*1em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == -3.14)*0.22em},     yshift = {(\tick == -3.14)*0.76em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.28em},         yshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.45em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == 3.14)*0.28em},      yshift = {(\tick == 3.14)*0.45em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == 6.28)*0.25em},      yshift = {(\tick == 6.28)*0.56em}},
% z labels
every z tick label/.style = {font = \fonts{11}, 
xshift = {(\tick == -1)*0.1em},        yshift = {(\tick == -1)*0.5em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.1em},     yshift = {(\tick == 0)*0.15em}, 
xshift = {(\tick == 1)*0.1em},         yshift = {(\tick == 1)*0.1em}}
}
% axis
\begin{axis}[
xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$, width = 10cm, view={30}{60}, 
ymin = -2*pi, ymax = 2*pi,
zmin = -1, zmax = 1, 
xtick = {-6.28, -3.14,..., 6.28}, 
ytick = {-6.28, -3.14,..., 6.28}, 
xticklabels = {$-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $0$, $\pi$, $2\pi$}, 
yticklabels = {$-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $0$, $\pi$, $2\pi$}]
% plot (samples = 65)
\addplot3[surf, samples = 5, domain = -2*pi:2*pi, y domain = -pi:2*pi, opacity = 0.5] {sin(deg(x))*cos(deg(y))};
\addplot3[domain = -2*pi:2*pi, fill = blue, opacity = 0.1, name path = top] (x, -pi, 1);
\addplot3[domain = -2*pi:2*pi, fill = blue, opacity = 0.1, name path = bottom] (x, -pi, -1);
\addplot3[fill = blue, opacity = 0.4] coordinates {(-6.28,-3.14,-1)(6.28,-3.14,-1)(6.28,-3.14,1)(-6.28,-3.14,1)(-6.28,-3.14,-1)};
\addplot3[domain = -2*pi:2*pi, line width = 1, samples=60, samples y = 0] ({x}, {-pi}, {-sin(deg(x))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very convenient workaround